# Consistently aggregate values using Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, aggregate, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a total count of "unread messages" that are stored in paths such as

`/messages/{my_id}/{friend_id}`

by creating a cloud function that is triggered at the above path, and when it is triggered it would update this path:

`/unread-messages-count/{my_id}`

So if `/messages/123` contains the following data:

```
{
   "200": { "msg1": "...", "msg2": "..." },
   "201": { "msg3": "...", "msg4": "...", "msg5": "..." },
}
```

I want `/unread-messages-count/123` to eventually have the value `5`.

And when the `"201"` subtree is set to `null`, I want `/unread-messages-count/123` to eventually have the value `2`.

The value must be consistent, so I used transaction inside a Cloud Function with onWrite trigger on `/messages/{my_id}/{friend_id}`:

```
onWrite((event) => {
     let oldCount = event.data.previous.numChildren;
     let newCount = event.data.current.numChildren;
     let delta = newCount - oldCount;

     let p = db.ref(`/unread-messages-count/${event.params.my_id}`).transaction((data) => {
         let oldTotal = !data ? 0 : data;
         let newTotal = oldTotal + delta;
         return newTotal;
     });

     return Promise.all([p])
        .then(() => { console.log('success'); });
}
```

So far it works perfectly (transactions are retried several times when there are a lot of concurrent writes), but today I encountered a weird case: the `current` contained 0 children and the `previous` contained 5 children, resulting in a `-5` change in the total unread count, but then a few seconds later the same situation occurred again, causing another `-5` change in the total unread count, making it invalid.

It seemed that the onWrite callback is triggered twice for some reason. Is it possible for this to happen?

What is an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: Is this predictable or repeatable in any way?

Comment: No, it happens randomly and rarely (1 out of about 1000 times). I have yet to encounter it the second time. Is there any guarantees about the execution of the onWrite callback? e.g. maximum once?

Comment: Cloud Functions uses pubsub behind the scenes to deliver changes to your function.  It turns out that CF has an "at-least-once" guarantee (as you can read here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview).  It might be that you're seeing an occasional rare duplicate because of some hiccup in the system.  In any event, I'd file a bug report (and link back here) to get a more official response: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/